# Logic in gradle/groovy scripting

Tags: gradle, groovy

I am new in groovy-gradle field, and right now I am taking multiple online courses, but I am missing something here.

I'll give you and example. This creates a Jar file:

```
apply plugin: 'java' // 1. Apply the Java plugin to the project

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'java' // 3. Add 'java' directory as a source directory
        }
    }
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Version': '1.0' // 2. Add manifest attribute
    }
}
```

You can find this solution everywhere, but not clear explanation.

Now, can apply plugin by:  `Plugin.apply(T)`
I assume that the Plugin is object instance and apply is its method and T is an an argument.
So what is what is `apply plugin "java"`?

There is also thing called sourceSets. It may be method that takes an argument of a Closure, or it may be a property that takes a Closure as argument because of default getter generated by groovy. 
I canot tell because in groovy equal sign is optional, parenthesis are optional.--- VERY INOVATIVE!!!!!!!!

And finally there is thing called main. I cannot find what it is, and I've been looking for it everywhere, even here :[https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSet.html](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/)

And this 'main'-ting contains thing called java (looks like instance of SourceDirectorySet), which contains method srcDir, that takes a string as an agument.

Does it makes sense to you?.
How to extract information from here:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/, and use it in a build?

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm on my mobile so it's difficult to explain all of the Gradle magic but this should help you on your way.

There is an implicit [Project](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html) instance in scope and much of what you see in a gradle script will delegate to this.

Eg

```
apply plugin: 'java'
```

Is equivalent to

```
getProject().apply([plugin: 'java'])
```

You can read more in the [writing a custom plugin section](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html) but there's a property file that maps "java" to [JavaPlugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/plugins/JavaPlugin.html)

When you applied the "java" plugin, this will "mixin" the [JavaPluginConvention](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.JavaPluginConvention.html) to the project (so you can now call getSourceSets() in java which can be shortened to "sourceSets" in groovy)

One feature that gets a lot of use in Gradle's DSL is Groovy's [methodMissing(...)](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/11/groovy-goodness-create-dynamic-methods.html?m=1). So

```
sourceSets.main { ... }
```

will actually get dynamically delegated to

```
sourceSets.getByName('main').configure { ... }
```

Another feature which is a source of "magic" is that in groovy you can write

```
def a = new A()
a.foo = 'bar'
a.baz('x')
```

As

```
def a = new A()
a.with {
    foo = 'bar'
    baz('x')
}
```

Hopefully you can see that all property/method references in the closure are delegated to the "a" instance. This style of configuration helps gradle scripts remain succinct.

See [the with method](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/09/groovy-goodness-with-method.html?m=1)

Comment: I am a guy who hate his so-called magic, because it forces me to remember a ton of gimmicks that I have to take into account and googling for explanation.
There is no way I could find that:    
sourceSets.main { ... } is same as : sourceSets.getByName('main').configure { ... } 
in reasonable amount of time.

So, do you think that Kotlin/Gradle would be a better for me?

Comment: It's a trade off, I'm also a guy who hates magic but with gradle I think it's worth it for the sake of readability. Typically you will read gradle scripts far more often than write them. As soon as you mentioned hating magic I was ready to suggest Kotlin as the magic is traceable and typed with code completion in intellij. I haven't tried the Kotlin dsl myself as I think it's a bit clunky and not as pretty as the groovy equivalent. The Kotlin script looks far more like code than the groovy equivalent. Are you willing to trade readability for type safety?

Comment: I think it's worth comparing with Maven where it's xml and it's all magic. If you can't find a maven sample on stack overflow you're usually stuck. With gradle I can just use the javadocs to do pretty much anything (assuming you know the "magic" bits) without needing to copy/paste from stack overflow (assuming someone had the exact same problem before)